# Combinations for 5 fruits distributed to 7 people

Tags: combinatorics

If I have 5 different fruits to distribute to 7 people, and each person can receive 0-5 fruits, how do I calculate the number of combinations?

It's been a while since I've calculated these but I would first think the answer is 5$^7$, but then aren't there really 6 possibilities if 0 is also a possibility? Does that make the answer 6$^7$?

Secondly, if I distribute the fruits so that one person can not receive more than one fruit, how is this calculated?

Would it be 5! = 120?

Comment: Do you mean fruit or book for the second part?

Comment: Also, do you have unlimited amounts of each fruit?

Comment: I fixed the typo and I have one of each fruit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First Case**:

The first fruit can be given to any of the $7$ people.

The second fruit can also be given to any of the $7$ people.

Similarly, the third,fourth and fifth fruits can also be given to any of the $7$ people.

So the number of choices of distributing the fruits is $7\times 7\times 7\times 7\times 7 = 7^5$.

**Second Case:**

The $5$ fruits can be distributed among the $7$ people in $\binom{7}{5}\times 5!$ ways since the people receiving $1$ fruit each can be chosen in $\binom{7}{5}$ ways and the fruits being different, they can be given to the five people in $5!$ ways.

Comment: That makes sense! So just to make sure I remember correctly - for the 2nd case there would be 21 x 5! combinations?

Comment: @mangopancake Yes, as you can see.

Comment: For the second case you could also say it like this: Give the first fruit to one of seven people, the next fruit to one of six people, and so forth until you're out of fruit

Comment: @Soke Yes, thats a valid way too.